# Cannot connect: Can't connect to lyh-efz.ms-acdc.office.com,995: Connection timed out

Tags: php, imap

```
    <?php

set_time_limit(3000);
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '';//email address
$password = '';//password

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "Log2.out file from Webcenter Prod"');


$max_emails = 1;

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {
    $count = 1;
    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';
    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);
    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);

         $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

                /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                 * have the attachment with the same file name.
                 */
                $fp = fopen("./" . $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
            }

        }

        if($count = $max_emails) break;

        /* output the email header information */
  /*      $output.= '<p><div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<p>Subject: <span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<p>From: <span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<p>Date: <span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';*/
        //$output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        /*$output.= '<p>Message:<div class="body">'.$message.'';
        $output.= '<p>attachment:'.$filename.'';
        $output.= '<table><tr><hr size="1" width="100%%" noshade color="black" ></tr></table>';*/


    }

    echo $output;
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

Above is the code I am using to save the attachment. The code is working fine in localhost but when I run it in server getting below error

Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:995/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /opt/lampp/htdocs/AMSDASH/v1/index2.php on line 9
Cannot connect: Can't connect to lyh-efz.ms-acdc.office.com,995: Connection timed out
Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to lyh-efz.ms-acdc.office.com,995: Connection timed out (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to lyh-efz.ms-acdc.office.com,995: Connection timed out (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to lyh-efz.ms-acdc.office.com,995: Connection timed out (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to lyh-efz.ms-acdc.office.com,995: Connection timed out (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How can you be sure the server is reachable at all. Have you tried with ping/trace/telnet?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel yes I tried with ping, its able to reach server

Comment: what happens when you try to connect to port 995 using telnet?

Comment: I can connect there using `openssl s_client -crlf -connect outlook.office365.com:993`. There's a firewall problem on that server.

Comment: Note that the code says port 993, the error messages say 995. I'm bet there's a typo somewhere.

Comment: @arnt firewall is not enabled on the server and about port number, im using 993. there is a type mistake in added code